# When a thread is done, how to notify the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use FTP raw commands to upload file to a FTP server, I start a new thread to send file via socket in my code. when the newly started thread finished sending file I want to output some message to console, how can I make sure the thread have finished it's work ?
here is my code:

```
TinyFTPClient ftp = new TinyFTPClient(host, port, user, pswd);
ftp.execute("TYPE A");
String pasvReturn = ftp.execute("PASV");
String pasvHost = TinyFTPClient.parseAddress(pasvReturn);
int pasvPort = TinyFTPClient.parsePort(pasvReturn);
new Thread(new FTPFileSender(pasvHost, pasvPort, fileToSend)).start();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ***how can I make sure the thread have finished it's work ?***

You do call [`Thread.join()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) like this:

```
...
Thread t = new Thread(new FTPFileSender(pasvHost, pasvPort, fileToSend));
t.start();

// wait for t to finish
t.join();
```

Note however that `Thread.join` will *block* until the other thread has finished.

A better idea is perhaps to encapsulate the upload-thread in a `UploadThread` class which performs some callback when it's done. It could for instance implement an `addUploadListener` and notify all such listeners when the upload is complete. The main thread would then do something like this:

```
UploadThread ut = new UploadThread(...);
ut.addUploadListener(new UploadListener() {
    public void uploadComplete() {
        System.out.println("Upload completed.");
    }
});

ut.start();
```

Comment: wouldn't this mean that the `UploadThread` (which you say performs some callback) invoked the the `onUploadComplete` on the worker thread and **not** on the main thread? The print you outline in your example will not be done on the main thread as far as I can see

Comment: That's right. It was a while ago I wrote the answer. If I rewrote it today, I would strongly encourage the reader to use executor services, callables and futures.

Answer (score 2):

For what you are trying to do, I see at least three ways to accomplish:

- you could just let the uploading thread itself print the logging message or
- in some other thread, you can [join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) the upload thread. Using this approach you could do some other work *before* calling `join`, otherwise there is no gain from doing it in a separate thread.
- you can implement some kind of listener, so an uploading `Thread` informs all registered listeners about it's progress. This is the most flexible solution, but also the most complex.